# python / django strptime "bad directive"

Tags: python, django, datetime, strptime

I'm trying to convert a string into a date object, I have this line of code:

```
datetime.strptime('01/04/2014', '%d/%m%/%y')
```

And I get:

```
ValueError: '/' is a bad directive in format '%d/%m%/%y'
```

I have tried changing / with other characters and also no separator but it throws up the same error (for that character)

Django 1.5.1
Python 2.7.3

Any idea what this means? Google doesn't throw up many results for the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one `%` too many after the `%m` directive; `%/` is not a valid directive and the `ValueError` tells you just that.

Use:

```
datetime.strptime('01/04/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

instead, using `%Y` (capital `Y`) to parse a year with century.

Demo:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('01/04/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: This is indeed the answer. Except for the %y code which expects a 2-digit year, use %Y instead.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer: *Way* ahead of you there. :-)

Comment: Wow. How embarrassed am I. Can't believe I didn't spot that. Thanks guys